# Algorithm for min/max when order in row

Tags: algorithms

I have 5 numbers which belongs to Z. 
I am trying to create an algorithm which gives the min and max from the set in only 6 iterations (the least we need to solve the problem).

The purpose in my method is set all numbers in a row from min to max, then the first is min and last is max.

for three numbers is like
if a>b then we use a temporary variable d=b
b=a
a=d
now i made a < b for sure.
the next iteration is
if b>c we do like above, then again a>c and last iteration is a>b again.
in this method we get an order for any three numbers when 'a' is min and 'c' is max.

However, for 5 numbers I have an problem when I`m trying to make the numbers in row with only 6 iterations.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need at least $7$ comparisons to sort $5$ numbers, because with two possible results from each comparison can distinguish $2^6=64$ different orderings with $6$ comparisions but there are $5!=120$ possible orderings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you try to do more work than necessary(sorting instead of only finding max/min).

My idea is the following:

Let A[0] to A[4] be your 5 numbers. First you set min = max = A[0]. Now you compare A[1] and A[2]. The larger of these numbers you compare with max, the smaller you compare with min. Now you compare A[3] to A[4]. Again you now compare the larger of these numbers to max and the smaller to min. In this way you have exactly 6 comparisons.